# Which one of security technique use for Apache and PHP?

Tags: php, apache2, debian, lamp

I always run Apache with default mpm-prefork and PHP as DSO(mod_php).
I going to make new LAMP server for me and couple friends and I would like to use the most effective security method.

I decided for Apache2 (although I know that nginx should be good choice for securit) and use mpm-itk instead of traditional prefork. My vision is that each web site will run under specific user. So far so good. For PHP I don't want to use DSO, I'd like to setup FastCGI (PHP-FPM).

But I really don't know if it will be compatible with each other.
For example user daniel (/home/daniel/www/...) will have web presentation that will run under him and php scrips will also run under him:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SuexecUserGroup daniel daniel

    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/daniel/www

    PHP_Fix_Pathinfo_Enable 1
    <Directory /home/daniel/www>
        Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FCGIWrapper /var/www/daniel/php5-wrap .php
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId daniel daniel
</IfModule>
```

I'm little bit desperate if it's good solution, if it will be work together. 
I will be really pleasure for any comments, ideas from your side.

Thanks in advance.

Daniel

Answer (score -1):

I found an interesting article on that subject.

http://www.slashroot.in/how-to-secure-apache-web-server

Comment: Welcome to SO Bram! This is not the answer to the question. Please add additional information as comment. And please visit the Tour [http://stackoverflow.com/tour]